# Docker, Windows 11 - How can I access localhost in a docker container from host?

Tags: windows, docker, dockerfile, docker-network

### Summary

- I'm trying to set up a Docker container to run an app on http://localhost:3000
- My container in Windows runs, but I don't get any response when accessing http://localhost:3000
- I would like to find out how to access http://localhost:3000 from my browser outside of the docker container please

### Configuration

##### DockerFile

```
FROM node:20

WORKDIR /code
COPY app.js /code/app.js

EXPOSE 3000

ENTRYPOINT [ "node", "/code/app.js", "-l", "-c" ]
```

##### app.js

```js
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

##### Build Image:

```bash
docker image build -t node-temp .
```

##### Run Container:

```bash
docker container run --rm -it -p 3000:3000 --name node-temp-container node-temp
```

##### It shows:

```
Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/
```

##### Problem:

But this is what I get when I access it from my browser. (Ignore the image requests, they are just some google dinosaur icons)

[image]

##### Note:

I get "Hello World" when running exec

```bash
docker container exec -it node-temp-container curl http://localhost:3000
Hello World
```

docker container inspect node-temp-container

```json
[
    {
        "Id": "0bbdd48455c6600dc9fa6256f91c1bd30ae8e49b0e641949c00c10f7c11a51f0",
        "Created": "2023-07-09T13:29:25.113334992Z",
        "Path": "node",
        "Args": [
            "/code/app.js",
            "-l",
            "-c"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 10523,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2023-07-09T13:29:29.399906481Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:724b009dc9067af9a7b35eda3f95cc54ff12f50a285ff38fa50d32a0cf31b697",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/0bbdd48455c6600dc9fa6256f91c1bd30ae8e49b0e641949c00c10f7c11a51f0/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/0bbdd48455c6600dc9fa6256f91c1bd30ae8e49b0e641949c00c10f7c11a51f0/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/0bbdd48455c6600dc9fa6256f91c1bd30ae8e49b0e641949c00c10f7c11a51f0/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/0bbdd48455c6600dc9fa6256f91c1bd30ae8e49b0e641949c00c10f7c11a51f0/0bbdd48455c6600dc9fa6256f91c1bd30ae8e49b0e641949c00c10f7c11a51f0-json.log",
        "Name": "/node-temp-container",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "3000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "3000"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": true,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "ConsoleSize": [
                89,
                178
            ],
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "host",
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": [],
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": [],
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": [],
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0d809c1293fffedf337773da406bd79fea8790d15c8afbd5954e9379ae58e086-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/p14b2jt8c0wy4viexwn1ng3p0/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/44pxwvm3lf1m78yno7zkn4ayn/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a52e4f60ff3f1d8743a73f55171951ac3db32653bb2b72be8f7a2ba202cc5e60/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2cc4aee08b2995aa3326ed2e7323cb30a57eed60bd11568d80ff974a411d95c2/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6bf164e32d1d2c11dc6903198cc538465bf9201b8218a5d09064a4769e2ce479/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4684a5c8dce524e9a8bd11195affe7a7c5577c58e298a40ea4c1fd22a16d7e14/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b4e94897f778e922f01bef76f02551c1227323aeed5082f3014b6ef158afb274/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/86847656ba4eb5d0e1ab5ad89bf9c92e333631f79205c10a49afcbc52493d0a7/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/82fb9f9033d02fcbaea0edcc33126f5dc54c5d4d28a8e26d9beb609432425383/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/523acd47c7904aca441e6a8daf793a4757a6a4368f6fe58e98fd4ffd6e717259/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0d809c1293fffedf337773da406bd79fea8790d15c8afbd5954e9379ae58e086/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0d809c1293fffedf337773da406bd79fea8790d15c8afbd5954e9379ae58e086/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0d809c1293fffedf337773da406bd79fea8790d15c8afbd5954e9379ae58e086/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "0bbdd48455c6",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "3000/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": true,
            "OpenStdin": true,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "NODE_VERSION=20.3.1",
                "YARN_VERSION=1.22.19"
            ],
            "Cmd": null,
            "Image": "node-temp",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/code",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "node",
                "/code/app.js",
                "-l",
                "-c"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "7ccc4b679d0827b61f25dc7102396e8be5cee53cd9cdaf74279613d74542a9bf",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "3000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "3000"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/7ccc4b679d08",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "3beb1faa5fbd8b0308577e2076267a44866701b34f6b7057e8e85ed992cd7456",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "abad347ccca84500ade5564fcc045e47a497ae1cf666d5403855e7f93d351cb1",
                    "EndpointID": "3beb1faa5fbd8b0308577e2076267a44866701b34f6b7057e8e85ed992cd7456",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

docker network inspect bridge

```json
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "abad347ccca84500ade5564fcc045e47a497ae1cf666d5403855e7f93d351cb1",
        "Created": "2023-07-08T08:59:39.380269538Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "0bbdd48455c6600dc9fa6256f91c1bd30ae8e49b0e641949c00c10f7c11a51f0": {
                "Name": "node-temp-container",
                "EndpointID": "3beb1faa5fbd8b0308577e2076267a44866701b34f6b7057e8e85ed992cd7456",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

### Environment

- Windows 11 Home (x64)
- Installed Docker Desktop for Windows - https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/windows-install/

#### Test Installation

The installation is fine because it works when running the below:

- docker pull nginx
- docker container run -p 80:80 --name nginx-container nginx
- Open (in host browser) http://localhost

This proves that I must have something wrong in my setup, because I can run the default nginx container, and access it from my browser outside of docker.

---

I basically want to set up a docker container for my dev environment of an app, but I can't access my app if it runs in a Docker container.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, be sure that `node` is listening in every network interface, not the container specific one.

Basically, in a standalone container, it means ensuring that `node` is listening for requests on `0.0.0.0`.

The way in which this behavior should be configured depends on the actual server side framework you are using.

As exemplified in the [nodejs documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp), if using `express`,  for instance, you need to perform something similar to the following:

```js
'use strict';

const express = require('express');

// Constants
const PORT = 8080;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';

// App
const app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(PORT, HOST, () => {
  console.log(`Running on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: Wow! This works! Can't believe it's just simple as that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That is great @Max!! You are welcome! I am happy to see that you were able to solve the issue.